# Installation without Root Access in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, cl, code-conversion, root-access

I have to compile Locally Aware NMS (lanms) in my remote server LINUX based with an user account without root access.

In lanms there is a script named adapter.cpp , I have to convert it to .pyd so that it works with python. I have given the code described here.

```
#include "pybind11/pybind11.h"
#include "pybind11/numpy.h"
#include "pybind11/stl.h"
#include "pybind11/stl_bind.h"

#include "lanms.h"

namespace py = pybind11;


namespace lanms_adaptor {

std::vector<std::vector<float>> polys2floats(const std::vector<lanms::Polygon> &polys) {
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> ret;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < polys.size(); i ++) {
        auto &p = polys[i];
        auto &poly = p.poly;
        ret.emplace_back(std::vector<float>{
                float(poly[0].X), float(poly[0].Y),
                float(poly[1].X), float(poly[1].Y),
                float(poly[2].X), float(poly[2].Y),
                float(poly[3].X), float(poly[3].Y),
                float(p.score),
                });
    }

    return ret;
}


/**
 *
 * \param quad_n9 an n-by-9 numpy array, where first 8 numbers denote the
 *      quadrangle, and the last one is the score
 * \param iou_threshold two quadrangles with iou score above this threshold
 *      will be merged
 *
 * \return an n-by-9 numpy array, the merged quadrangles
 */
std::vector<std::vector<float>> merge_quadrangle_n9(
        py::array_t<float, py::array::c_style | py::array::forcecast> quad_n9,
        float iou_threshold) {
    auto pbuf = quad_n9.request();
    if (pbuf.ndim != 2 || pbuf.shape[1] != 9)
        throw std::runtime_error("quadrangles must have a shape of (n, 9)");
    auto n = pbuf.shape[0];
    auto ptr = static_cast<float *>(pbuf.ptr);
    return polys2floats(lanms::merge_quadrangle_n9(ptr, n, iou_threshold));
  }

 }

PYBIND11_PLUGIN(adaptor) {
py::module m("adaptor", "NMS");

m.def("merge_quadrangle_n9", &lanms_adaptor::merge_quadrangle_n9,
        "merge quadrangels");

return m.ptr();
}
```

To convert it I have used the following command.

> cl adaptor.cpp ./include/clipper/clipper.cpp /I ./include /I "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include" /LD /Fe:adaptor.pyd /link/LIBPATH:"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\libs"

It shows an error:

> Command 'cl' not found, but can be installed with:

> apt install cl-launch

> Please ask your administrator.

Furthermore, I don't have the root access. Is there any other way to install "cl" without administrator privileges?

The other way to compile lanms is need to install the g++ compiler in order to compile the adaptar.cpp file.

> sudo apt-get install build-essential

It is also asking for the administrator privileges.

Comment: `cl` is the visual studio compiler, you probably don't need that. `cl-launch` is [shell wrapper for Common Lisp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/cl-launch.1.html)

Comment: just to be sure as it is not entirely clear from the question: have you checked whether `gcc` available on this system?

Comment: if not - if you have `python` and `pip` available, you should able to install `pip` packages using the `--user` flag. conveniently, there exist a few packages on PyPI that allow compiling C++ code, namely, zig: https://pypi.org/project/ziglang/

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid, that it is almost impossible to compile your code on a machine that doesn't have a compiler installed.

The best option, that I can come up with, would be to set up a virtual machine, that runs the same version of the same linux distribution as the server. In that virtual machine, you have root access and can install a compiler. After compiling the code you just copy the program/library to the server. It is however not guaranteed, that the program compiled in the virtual machine will run without problems on the real server.